# Change JTable Background Color

Tags: java, swing, background, jtable

I am trying to change the background of a `JTable` in a swing based GUI. I have added the table to a `JScrollPane`. However, the area of the table where there are no cells does not change color. I tried changing the background and foreground color of the scroll pane. However, that does not help either. What component of JTable do I need to edit to change the white background. Below is the part of my code.

```
public class UiColors {
    public static Color BACKGROUND_COLOR_DARK = new Color(30,30,30);
    public static Color BACKGROUND_COLOR_LIGHT = new Color(70,70,70);
    public static Color GOLDEN_TEXT = new Color(255, 215, 0);
}
```

Code for JTable

```
JScrollPane mdScrolPane = new JScrollPane();
mdScrolPane.setBackground(UiColors.BACKGROUND_COLOR_DARK);
mdScrolPane.setOpaque(false);
mdScrolPane.setForeground(UiColors.BACKGROUND_COLOR_DARK);
contentPane.add(mdScrolPane, "cell 1 0 1 5,grow");

mdTableModel = new ReadOnlyTableModel();

for (String col : columnNames) {
    mdTableModel.addColumn(col);
}

marketDataTable = new JTable(mdTableModel);
marketDataTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
marketDataTable.setToolTipText("Quotes");
marketDataTable.setBorder(null);
marketDataTable.setForeground(new Color(255, 215, 0));
marketDataTable.setBackground(UiColors.BACKGROUND_COLOR_DARK);
marketDataTable.setOpaque(false);
mdScrolPane.setColumnHeaderView(marketDataTable);
mdScrolPane.setViewportView(marketDataTable);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this line, that work for me :

```
mdScrolPane.getViewport().setBackground(UiColors.BACKGROUND_COLOR_DARK);
```

And try to replace the following code before JscrollPanel`` declaration :

**Replace the following code position :**

```
mdTableModel = new ReadOnlyTableModel();

for (String col : columnNames) {
    mdTableModel.addColumn(col);
}

marketDataTable = new JTable(mdTableModel);
marketDataTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
marketDataTable.setToolTipText("Quotes");
marketDataTable.setBorder(null);
marketDataTable.setForeground(new Color(255, 215, 0));
marketDataTable.setBackground(UiColors.BACKGROUND_COLOR_DARK);
marketDataTable.setOpaque(false);
```

**To be Befor :**

```
JScrollPane mdScrolPane = new JScrollPane();
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. I knew it just a component I missing.